# YARN Container has latent processes after being killed

Tags: containers, hadoop-yarn, kill

I've been playing with the distributed shell examples and I've noticed that when I kill a long running application the process persists. For example, if I kill a distshell app with `sleep 1000` as the command a few seconds after the container started, a process will still show

```
yarn        33138   0.0  0.0  2432752    508   ??  S    12:20PM   0:00.00 sleep 1000
```

I thought that YARN would be good about cleaning up child processes?  Perhaps this only applies to JAVA processes ?

Comment: This is after calling `yarn application -kill appid`